# How to accomplish the apache knox gateway high available?

Tags: knox-gateway

At the site Apache Knox Gateway 0.13.x User’s Guide(http://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-13-0/user-guide.html#High+Availability).
I want to configure the Knox High Availability and the first step in the site is to Configure Knox instances which are below

> All Knox instances must be synced to use the same topology credential keystores. >These files are located under >{GATEWAY_HOME}/conf/security/keystores/{TOPOLOGY_NAME}-credentials.jceks. They >are generated after the first topology deployment. Currently these files need to >be synced manually. Here are the steps to sync topologies credentials keystores:
>
> > 1. Choose a Knox instance that will be the source for topology credential keystores. Let’s call it keystores master
> > 2. Replace the topology credential keystores in the other Knox instances with topology credential keystores from the keystores master
> > 3. Restart Knox instances

I want to know how to finishe it.
Do I remove all the /{TOPOLOGY_NAME}-credentials.jceks and keep one ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you choose one of the Knox instances that will be a master (nothing special in being master). You then backup topology credential keystores in the other Knox instances as mentioned in the guide. Then copy the master topology credential keystores into the other instances. 
Do not delete anything. and restart all Knox instances.